# SwiftUI: control zIndex on views with matchedGeometryEffect

Tags: swiftui, z-index, picker, segmentedcontrol, swiftui-geometryeffect

I am building a custom SegmentedPicker in SwiftUI where the selector adjusts its size to fit the frame of each picker item. I did it already using `PreferenceKey`s as inspired by this post ([Inspecting the View Tree](https://swiftui-lab.com/communicating-with-the-view-tree-part-1/)) for uniformly sized items like shown below:

[image]

I think I can simplify my implementation considerably and avoid using `PreferencyKey`s altogether by using a `.matchedGeometryEffect()`. My idea was to present a selector behind each item only when that item has been selected and sync the transition using the `.matchedGeometryEffect()`. Almost everything is working except for an issue where the selector will be in front of the previously selected item. I tried explicitly setting the `zIndex`, but it does not seem to affect the result:

[image]

The code:

```
struct MatchedGeometryPicker: View {
    @Namespace private var animation
    @Binding var selection: Int
    let items: [String]
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(items.indices) { index in
                ZStack {
                    if isSelected(index) {
                        Color.gray.clipShape(Capsule())
                            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "selector", in: animation)
                            .animation(.easeInOut)
                            .zIndex(0)
                    }
                    
                    itemView(for: index)
                        .padding(7)
                        .zIndex(1)
                }
                .fixedSize()
            }
        }
        .padding(7)
    }
    
    func itemView(for index: Int) -> some View {
        Text(items[index])
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
            .foregroundColor(isSelected(index) ? .black : .gray)
            .font(.caption)
            .onTapGesture { selection = index }
    }
    
    func isSelected(_ index: Int) -> Bool { selection == index }
}
```

And in `ContentView`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selection = 0
    
    let pickerItems = [ "Item 1", "Long item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Long item 5"]
    
    var body: some View {
        MatchedGeometryPicker(selection: $selection, items: pickerItems)
            .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.10).clipShape(Capsule()))
            .padding(.horizontal, 5)
        
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: why working code with PreferenceKeys is not good for use and trying this way?

Comment: @swiftPunk with PreferenceKeys it works well if every item has the same frame, but I am still trying to solve an animation issue with the selector dimensions. Using the `.matchedGeometryEffect()`, the selector animates the position & dimension changes perfectly and the code is a lot simpler. I just need to figure out how to solve the layering issue...

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve all the animation issues I had with the picker implementation that uses `PreferenceKey`s when the items have different frame sizes. This does not solve the issue I have with the `zIndex` and the `.matchedGeometryEffect()`, so I will not accept my own answer, but I'll post it as a reference in case anyone needs it in the future.

The code:

```
public struct PKPicker: View {
    @Binding var selection: Int
    @State private var frames: [CGRect] = []
    let items: [String]
    
    public init(
        selection: Binding<Int>,
        items: [String])
    {
        self._selection = selection
        self._frames = State(wrappedValue: Array<CGRect>(repeating: CGRect(),
                                                         count: items.count))
        self.items = items
    }
    
    public var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
            selector
            HStack {
                ForEach(items.indices)  { index in
                    itemView(for: index)
                        
                }
            }
        }
        .onPreferenceChange(PKPickerItemPreferenceKey.self) { preferences in
            preferences.forEach { frames[$0.id] = $0.frame }
        }
        .coordinateSpace(name: "picker2")
        
    }
    
    var selector: some View {
        Color.gray.opacity(0.25).clipShape(Capsule())
            .frame(width: frames[selection].size.width,
                   height: frames[selection].size.height)
            .offset(x: frames[selection].minX, y: frames[selection].minY)
    }
    
    func itemView(for index: Int) -> some View {
        Text(items[index])
            .fixedSize()
            .padding(7)
            .foregroundColor(isSelected(index) ? .black : .gray)
            .font( .caption)
            .onTapGesture { selection = index }
            .background(PKPickerItemPreferenceSetter(id: index))
            
    }
    
    func isSelected(_ index: Int) -> Bool {
        index == selection
    }
}

struct PKPickerItemPreferenceData: Equatable {
    let id: Int
    let frame: CGRect
}

struct PKPickerItemPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    typealias Value = [PKPickerItemPreferenceData]

    static var defaultValue: [PKPickerItemPreferenceData] = []
    
    static func reduce(
        value: inout [PKPickerItemPreferenceData],
        nextValue: () -> [PKPickerItemPreferenceData])
    {
        value.append(contentsOf: nextValue())
    }
}

struct PKPickerItemPreferenceSetter: View {
    let id: Int
    let coordinateSpace = CoordinateSpace.named("picker2")
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            Color.clear
                .preference(key: PKPickerItemPreferenceKey.self,
                            value: [PKPickerItemPreferenceData(
                                        id: id, frame: geometry.frame(in: coordinateSpace))])
        }
    }
}
```

And in `ContentView`

struct ContentView: View {
@State private var selection = 0

```
let pickerItems = [ "Item 1", "Long item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Long Item 5"]

var body: some View {
    PKPicker(selection: $selection.animation(.easeInOut), items: pickerItems)
        .padding(7)
        .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.10).clipShape(Capsule()))
        .padding(5)
    
}
```

Result:

[image]